# Rewrite doesn't work?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to write a rewritrule in my htaccess file on my `000webhost` account but I cannot find a way to make it work!

all the files are uploaded to the root directory (public_html). the `.htaccess` file is in the same directory as well.

in the URL address bar i get something like this: `domain.com/index.php?city=London`

I need this to change to `domain.com/city/London`

But nothing seem to work via `htaccess` file!

here is my htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^city/([^/]*)$ /index.php?city=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

any help would be great.

Comment: try replace `*` to `+`.

Comment: Are you sure that the server allows you to change the configuration from .htaccess file? You can check that by putting some garbage into this file and seeing if error 500 will show up.

Comment: @M1K1O, That did the trick but as deceze mentioned bellow i have to write the city/london in the address bar in order to see it! it wont do it automatically if you know what i mean! any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get proper 'nice urls', you'll need to redirect ugly url's to nice url's, and internally rewrite nice url's to the ugly, actually working, url's. You already have the internal rewrite.

From Apache 2.3.9 on, you can use the following solution. The `END`-flag is not available in earlier versions and will throw an internal server error when used. Change the `R` to `R=301` to make the redirect permanent. Only do this when all redirects and rewrites are working as you want them, as browsers will cache permanent redirects. The END-flag will stop rewriting completely, and will prevent an infinite loop.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} city=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /city/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^city/([^/]*)$ /index.php?city=$1 [END]
```

In earlier versions of Apache, you'll need to use a hack. This works, because `%{THE_REQUEST}` is only available like this with external requests, not when the url is rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/index\.php\?city=(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ city/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^city/([^/]*)$ /index.php?city=$1 [L]
```

Please note that I can't test either RewriteRule on this computer, but I am fairly sure I didn't make a typo.

Comment: I've used your second code and it almost worked BUT in the address bar it shows domain.com/city/london?city=london. I need it to show domain.com/city/london. am I doing anything wrong or missing something?

Comment: Add a trailing `?` behind the first RewriteRule. This will clear the query string. I've changed it in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess work properly. In case, of user will visit the page `domain.com/index.php?city=LondonYou` you can redirect him. By header location.

```
 header("Location: city/".$_GET['city']);
```

And now you need just know, when is user access by htacces and when not. Just use some trick.

```
RewriteRule ^city/([^/]*)$ /index.php?city=$1&accessByHtaccess [L]
```

With condition.

```
 if(!$_GET['accessByHtaccess ']){
   header("Location: city/".$_GET['city']);
 }
```